# How do you group by hourly increments in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

In MySQL, what's a good way to count data in a single table into hourly buckets?

I've tried,

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tournament GROUP BY HOUR(date_created)
```

But this will group hours from different days together as it is just using the hour numeric value as a grouper.

I'd like to use `date_created` as the grouper, but without units of time less the hour. But there might be a better way to accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the date use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to include all the significant parts up to the hour:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

`DATE_FORMAT` returns a string, to get a MySQL DateTime, use the following

```
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Comment: That looks like the clearest simplest solution. Does that create a String or a Timestamp with the extraneous parts removed?

Comment: Documentation says it it returns a String, is there away to something similar that returns a timestamp?

Comment: I'm not at a place where I can try this, but I think you can do a `STR_TO_DATE` on the result using the same format string, something like `STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H')`.

Comment: Looks like STR_TO_DATE works, thanks. I ended up marking Rolando's answer because it worked out better for me but yours is also useful.

Comment: No problem - glad you have an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(date_created), MONTH(date_created), DAY(date_created), HOUR(date_created)
```

Answer (score 1):

I supposed that your `date_created` column is `DATETIME` format think you can just `GROUP BY` hours, days and month (maybe years)?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tournament GROUP BY HOUR(date_created), DAY(date_created), MONTH(date_created)
```

#### You can check date and time function's documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using the timetsamp of the date, you can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1),TimeStampHour FROM
(
    SELECT
        FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) -
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created),3600)) TimeStampHour
    FROM tournament
) A GROUP BY TimeStampHour;
```

or if you just want the timestamp as a number

```
SELECT COUNT(1),TimeStampHour FROM
(
    SELECT
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) -
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created),3600) TimeStampHour
    FROM tournament
) A GROUP BY TimeStampHour;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## Explanation

The reason the number 3600 is used is that there are 3600 seconds in a hour. You need to substract the modulus of a timestamp and 3600 to get the number of seconds to remove from the timestamp to get the timestamp of an exact hour.

Here is sample code to demonstrate this:

```
SELECT *,
    ts_now - ts_extra ts_hr,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(ts_now - ts_extra) hr
FROM
(SELECT
    NOW() now,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) ts_now,
    MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),3600) ts_extra
) A;
```

When I run it now, I get this

```
mysql> SELECT *,
    ->     ts_now - ts_extra ts_hr,
    ->     FROM_UNIXTIME(ts_now - ts_extra) hr
    -> FROM
    -> (SELECT
    ->     NOW() now,
    ->     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) ts_now,
    ->     MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),3600) ts_extra
    -> ) A;
+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| now                 | ts_now     | ts_extra | ts_hr      | hr                  |
+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| 2013-06-04 11:52:10 | 1370361130 |     3130 | 1370358000 | 2013-06-04 11:00:00 |
+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, in my case generating a timestamp is more useful then the string method answer given by Ed Gibbs.